# Static text blocks between simple product's custom options

Tags: custom-options

I like to add static Text fields (output not user input) between simple product's custom options. After long research I could find a proper extension or a solution for this..

The text parts will be different for each product.

Comment: You mean you couldn't find a solution? Is the text different for every product or for every attribute? Or both? Please explain EXACTLY what do you want to achieve.

Comment: The answer by Sander is correct, but doesn't work.
Reason for that is because it is missing a closing bracket. it should be: if (!is_null($block->getContent()))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying but if you want a static block per product per custom option you should use the file `frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml`, copy it to your custom template directory and then add the following code to the bottom (replacing the old code starting from around line `189`

```
   <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
<?php 
    $block_id = "custom_opt_{$_option->getData('product_id')}_{$_option->getData('option_id')}";
    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block_id);
    if (!is_null($block->getContent())
    {
        echo $block->getContent();
    }
?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now you can add a static block in the backend with the identifier `custom_opt_[product_id]_[custom option id]` which will be displayed above the corresponding custom option